# PC has 6 processors but shows 12 in task manager

Tags: windows-7, cpu-cores

This command:

```
WMIC CPU Get /Format:List
```

says that the machine has 6 cores, yet looking at the CPU Usage History in the Task Manager, there are 12 windows, not 6.

Why the discrepancy?

HP z600 - Windows 7

[image]

Comment: Hyperthreading?

Comment: Which CPU is installed in the machine? What does that same command list for "NumberOfLogicalProcessors"?

Comment: What is the result of: `wmic cpu get name`

Do you have more than one physical CPU?

Comment: Yes, 2 of these: `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU  E5649 @ 2.53Ghz`

Comment: Well, for the record: It's not Hyper-Threading (present, but probably disabled). There are simply two six-core CPUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wmic cpu get numberoflogicalprocessors`

That will return your logical processors. This includes HyperThreading on Intel processors.

If you want Physical cores (including multiple processor setups you can use:

`wmic cpu get numberofcores`

Windows Task Manager (At least through Windows 7) will show logical cores, not physical cores. This is because the Operating System treats all logical processors the same in its task scheduling.

Comment: Both of these commands return:  6  6

Comment: `both return: ` ?

Comment: Added screenshot to show command results

Answer (score 2):

This could be a result of [HyperThreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading), where there are multiple virtual cores per each physical CPU core.